# How do I use C# Variable in asp:HyperLinkField?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's what I have. The page loads but the hyperlinks are not hyperlinks. I view the source code of the page in my browser and I see the same string in the a href as in the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` attribute below. I have tried many different methods and either get no link or error during executing.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="LIDCode" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString='<%# Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"] %>?LC={0:d}&DD=true'>
</asp:HyperLinkField>
```

Comment: For some reason my Here's what I have code didn't show up. Here it is again...<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="LIDCode" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString='<%# Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"] %>?LC={0:d}&DD=true'>
</asp:HyperLinkField>

Answer (score 0):

If the DataNavigateUrlFormatString was giving me trouble because I couldn't embed an inline server tag inside a property of another server tag (that is the problem), what I'd do is set the DataNavigateUrlFormatString property in the code behind, for example in the Page_Load Event

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

       string strUrlFormat = Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"] + "?LC={0:d}&DD=true"
       // get the gridview object and set the DataNavigateUrlFormatString property for the column in question here...  so if you gridview ID = "myGridView" and it is the third column...
       myGridView.Columns[2].DataNavigateUrlFormatString = strUtlFormat;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:
-   Create public static method GetLink()
-   Update code like in hyperlink to look like this

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString='<%# PageName.GetLink() %>' 

public static string GetLink()
{
    //needs to be completed but you see the point
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"];
}
```